# last-child not working for nav menu want to take out content: " - "

Tags: css, css-selectors

The last-child is not working on the nav , I want to take out the content " - " for the last-child

```css
.main-navigation {
 clear: both;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 1140px;
 min-height: 45px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}

ul.nav-menu,
div.nav-menu > ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 40px 0 0;
}

.nav-menu li {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}

.nav-menu li a {
 color: #d76b02;
 display: block;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 1;
 padding: 15px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: capitalize;
}

.nav-menu li:hover > a,
.nav-menu li a:hover {
 /*background-color: #220e10;*/
 color: #d76b02;
 /*font-weight: bold;;*/
}

.nav-menu .sub-menu,
.nav-menu .children {
 background-color: #220e10;
 border: 2px solid rgba(247, 245, 231, 1);
 border-top: 0;
 color: #fff;
 display: none;
 float: left;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 left: -2px;
 top: 45px;
 z-index: 99999;
}

.nav-menu .sub-menu ul,
.nav-menu .children ul {
 border-left: 0;
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
}

ul.nav-menu ul a,
.nav-menu ul ul a {
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0;
 width: 200px;
}

ul.nav-menu ul a:hover,
.nav-menu ul ul a:hover {
 background-color: #db572f;
}

ul.nav-menu li:hover > ul,
.nav-menu ul li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}

.nav-menu .current_page_item > a,
.nav-menu .current_page_ancestor > a,
.nav-menu .current-menu-item > a,
.nav-menu .current-menu-ancestor > a {
 color: #bc360a;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.menu-toggle {
 display: none;
}

.nav-menu li a:after {
    content: " - ";
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.nav-menu ul:last-child li:last-child a:last-child {
 background-color: : red;

}

/* Navbar */
.navbar {
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
/* max-width: 1600px; */
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: -22px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid  #d76b02;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar site-boxed">
  <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <h3 class="menu-toggle">Menu</h3>
    <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="Skip to content">Skip to content</a>
    <div class="menu-test-container">
      <ul id="menu-test" class="nav-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-113" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-113"><a href="http://localhost/my-account/">My Account</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-114" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-114"><a href="http://localhost/checkout/">Checkout</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-115" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-115"><a href="http://localhost/cart/">Cart</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-116" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-116"><a href="http://localhost/shop/">Shop</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-148" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-146 current_page_item menu-item-148"><a href="http://localhost/">Home Page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I have some added as much of code as possible, I have tried many things and it has not worked.

I am trying to add a menu to my site but I don't want the last child to have content: " - " ;

https://jsfiddle.net/hazephase/fabgx9tt/

Comment: There is no `.nav-menu` element in that code (and) you have to remove the content from the `:after` which I don't see in your code. Rest looks fine. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fabgx9tt/1/).

Comment: @Harry look carefully. `<ul id="menu-test" class="nav-menu">`

Comment: @SergeyKhalitov: Don't know where my comment went, maybe deleted it accidentally :P It was my mistake, I missed the class in the middle of the unformatted code (and didn't expect it to be on the `ul` itself, was expecting on a parent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the last-child of `li` in an `ul` not the `ul` as last-child

```
nav ul li:last-child a:after {
    content: "";
}
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lb9tm9g/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-menu li:last-child a:after {
    content: "  ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is:

```
.nav-menu li:last-child a:after {
   content: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fabgx9tt/2/)

And format your html or other code in future please.